# mySQL + php, Show related posts to a tag from another table in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so I have 5 tags on my front page, I want to show 5 comments related to each tag, the tags are stored in one table, and the comments in another. I have a field in the comments table called "relatedID" wich is equal to the tags table id column.
the tags are sorted by the 5 highest ranked tags from the last 20 entries into the table.

My query:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tags WHERE countrycode='$lang[LANGUAGE]' ORDER BY timedate DESC LIMIT 20) tmp, comments WHERE comments.related = '1' && comments.lang = '$lang[LANGUAGE]' && comments.relatedID = tmp.id ORDER BY tmp.rank ASC LIMIT 5");

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($q)) { 
echo $result['tag'],'<br />';
echo $result['comment'],'<br />';
}
```

I want it to look like this:

Tag 1
comment 1
comment 2
comment 3
comment 4
comment 5

Tag 2 
comment 1
comment 2
comment 3
comment 4
comment 5

Tag 3

And so on..

Any simple solution to this?

Now it only show up with the same tag and same 5 comments x 5 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a second query:

```
// Query tags
$q = mysql_query("...");

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($q)) { 
    echo $result['tag'],'<br />';
    // Query comments
    $q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ... LIMIT 5");
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
        echo $result['comment'],'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: What if he has lots and lots of tags?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen What if he has many bananas? I guess he would make a new question and tell us what problems he has with his bananas. Maybe someone would tell him to use a LIMIT and OFFSET. We will never know ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in one query using [mysql user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). The query above will return the 5 last comments of your 5 top ranked tags.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        @nb:=if(@prev_id=tags.id,@nb+1,1) as nb_com,
        @prev_id:=tags.id
    FROM (SELECT @prev_id:=0, @nb:=0, @nb_tag:=0, @prev_tag:=0) x, tags
    INNER JOIN comments on comments.relatedId = tags.id
    WHERE comments.lang = '$lang[LANGUAGE]'
    ORDER BY tags.rank, comments.timedate DESC
) D
where nb_com <= 5
AND if(@prev_tag=id,@nb_tag:=@nb_tag,@nb_tag:=@nb_tag+1)
AND @nb_tag <= 5
AND @prev_tag:=id
```

I assumed that you have a timedate column in your comments table. Replace this with whatever order you like.

If you want to know more about user variables, take a look at this [article](http://www.mysqldiary.com/user-defined-variables/)

EDIT : query edited to remove the LIMIT

Comment: This looks really good, but now I'm getting the error: _Every derived table must have its own alias_

Comment: Oops. Fixed :) I haven't tested it sorry. It should be ok now.

Comment: Actually, it didnt work afterall, if I set the LIMIT to 25, it will show the first 5 tags and first 5 comments and then show comment and tag 6 & 7, 20 times. if i LIMIT to 5, it shows 5 tags and 1 comment on each tag.

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer. I just tried it on a local database and it worked.

Comment: Couldnt make it work, it returned all the entries in my database. So I went with 2 querys instead. thanks for your effort thought.